# Sass cli dumps exceptions to output css

Tags: css, exception, sass, command-line-interface

My php framework (yii2) uses sass-cli(Sass 3.4.18) to automatically convert scss to css.

When error occurs sass-cli dumps exception to output css file as body:after content.

I don't want this behavior, but i can't find how to turn this off.

Sass reference says that there is :full_exception option that controls this, but i don't use any ruby framework and there is no corresponding cli option.

Github issue https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1185 says that :full_exception is now turned on by default.

How can i turn this off?

As i see it the easiest solution is to use Compass which has some config.rb file, which, as i understand, can be used to control :full_exception option.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Can't you set the option to false when you call the assetparser in php? http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/assetparser/

Comment: It seems like it would be simpler to just, you know, fix the error that causes the exception to be raised in the first place.

Comment: @cimmanon True, but for future debugging he might want to change this behaviour. We all like our workspace to be perfect for us personally.

Comment: @bram  i don't use assetparser and even after looking at it, seems not a good idea to use some outdated thirdparty tool that mimics sass. but thanks for additional variant

Comment: @cimmanon yeah, it works for now, but it kind of uncomfortable to know that there is a possibility that user will see changed page layout with ugly (for user) exception text

Comment: I don't know if that setting will do anything (never used it), but you can don't need Compass to do this.  The -r flag allows you to import Ruby code (eg. `sass -r path/to/my.rb`).  Why would the user be seeing an error at all?  Are you compiling on a production server?

Comment: @cimmanon yes, in production, but only once after i checked out modified scss files. my project is on very early stage and there is no need in precompiling. -r option didn't work for me or i don't know what to place in rb file. for now, i guess i ll just follow your first advice - just fix error) and test, test, test before production... thanks